# How to pass an id in the uri of eventKey of an NavItem ? I tried : eventKey={'demandes/${dem.id}'} but it comes as a string , anybody?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, navbar, sidenav

How to pass an id in the uri of eventKey of an NavItem ? I tried : eventKey={'demandes/${dem.id}'}, but it comes as a string, anybody?

[image]

*Thank you**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: It looks like you want the result of a loading event/ url call as a key, is that correct? You will have to do a call to a function which will return the result as a string... otherwise your string should be 'demandes/'+{dem.id} , normal apo's not backticks